# stop pretty pagination rewrite site.com/cat/2 => site.com/cat?page=2

Tags: pagination, urls, rewrite-rules

I need to be able to keep pretty URLs, but I need to be able to send page as a URL arg.

WordPress likes to do `site.com/cat/2/` for page two, but I need `site.com/cat?page=2` because we are moving some previously written JS for another system onto WordPress.

In this case, instead of rewriting all the JS pagination code, it seems easier to figure out how to rewrite the `/2/` into `?page=2` in WP.

Right now, if I put `site.com/cat?page=2` into the browser location input, the site converts it to `site.com/cat/2/` - which I don't want to happen, I want to keep it as `?page=2`.

Any suggestions welcome, thanks.